# No browser's windows will open after upgrading to 22.04 64-bit from 32-bit

Tags: firefox, dell, 64-bit

No browser's windows will open properly, though browsers start, after installing 22.04 64-bit (overwriting 18.04 32-bit that worked fine) on Dell Inspiron 530 4GB/64GB SSD (Core2Duo). Firefox, Chromium, and Google Chrome all behave similarly. Other apps open correctly including LibreOffice writer, file manager, text editor, and terminal (internet works). I tried two different monitors, selecting various display resolutions, with no effect.

Empty Firefox window:

[image: Screenshot with empty Firefox window thumbnail]

Comment: What do you mean by "*not open properly*". I have no idea what you're trying to show with your picture and what we should be looking at, nor what your issue is. I'm involved with QA (*Quality Assurance*) & use c2d devices in testing; but lack of details & understanding of your issue means I can't help. Was your install clean? as you mention upgrade; did you *upgrade via re-install*?  (ie. no-format)  Are there any crash files? Have you tried running from terminal & seen messages (*snap* browsers vary slightly to *deb* browsers; eg. `snap run chromium --enable-logging=stderr --v=1` for clues)

Comment: Try logging in on an Xorg session to check whether this is an issue related to Wayland.

Comment: I've since found that browsers work correctly using the live version of 22.04, which is acceptable here if not ideal. It's not likely a hardware problem because everything worked correctly on 18.04 32-bit before the clean install of 22.04 64-bit. I've also since clean installed and run Win10 over 22.04 w/o issue, but the browsers fail when 22.04 is installed again alongside Win10.

Comment: @guiverc - "Not open properly" is hard to describe but you can see the strange intersection of the Settings and libraoffice windows that's caused by the invisible Firefox window. Chromium doesn't open any window.

Maybe relevant from 'snap run chromium' at https://drive.google.com/file/d/18KIgkkrPtKymmMwcf0U9QiKAY2ytJga1/ ?:
`Gtk-Message: 10:01:01.480: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`
`Gtk-Message: 10:01:01.482: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`
`libGL error: Version 4 or later of flush extension not found`
`libGL error: failed to load driver: i915`

Thank you

Comment: @vanadium - I'd appreciate any pointer to info on how to log in on an Xorg session that complements the Xorg man page.

Comment: At the login screen, select the gear icon in the corner and from the dropdown, select the ubuntu entry, not "ubuntu on Wayland". Also, try a "force reload from web" (vs cache) with Alt+R in Firefox.  Firefox has a cache problem sometimes, and the cached page is blank.

Comment: Selecting "Ubuntu on Xorg" instead of "Ubuntu" at login enabled Firefox to start correctly. If this should submitted as a bug pls let me know. Thx @ubfan1

Comment: Firefox works for me on Wayland, U22.04, so something else must be causing problems.  I'm on Nvidia 515.